# cv_bridge tutorials not working

Tags: ros, cv-bridge, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running the example code from the [cv_bridge tutorial,](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) all I see is a small window that has captured a small portion of my screen, along with terminal output that says `init done` and some blank space. I ran `catkin_make` in my `catkin_ws` and have received no build errors. As you can tell, I am able to run the node but don't receive the normal output. To start connection with the drone I did `rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver _realtime_navdata:=True _realtime_video:=True  _navdata_demo:=1` in order to ensure that the realtime video publishing and Navdata were enabled for the drone. I also ran the stated command without the extra parameters. I am using OpenCV 3.2 with the Parrot 1 AR drone and am currently using ROS Kinetic on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. However when I execute `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/ardrone/front/image_raw`, I can see the camera feed.  Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265801/cv_bridge-tutorials-not-working/) by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2017-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for the record and people having the same issue I'm adding this comment. I was also having problems following that tutorial so I've changed the topic name to /usb_cam/image_raw so it works now!

---

Originally posted by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) with karma: 75 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0